# Error integerField django models syncdb

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am developing an application with python djnago and I'm new to it so my question may sound very primitive I face this error when trying to run syncdb

```
 TypeError: Error when calling the metaclass bases
    unbound method contribute_to_class() must be called with IntegerField 
    instance as first argument (got ModelBase instance instead)
```

here is a code snippet from models.py

```
 class Type(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    description = models.CharField(max_length = 200)   

class TypeModel(models.Model):
    importance = models.IntegerField
    name = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)    
    type = models.ForeignKey(Type)
```

When I try to run the following command

```
   python manage.py syncdb
```

I get the error on the top of the question 
I also have to say that it used to work perfectly just before I add TypeModel to models.py file where am I making mistake I'll be thankful if anyone can help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your `importance = models.IntegerField`, good `models.IntegerField(default=0)` or `models.IntegerField()`

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the parentheses for the function. Do this:

```
importance = models.IntegerField()
```

instead of:

```
importance = models.IntegerField
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer you also gave me the right answer I tried to vote you up and realized I can't do it I'll remember to do that as soon as I become able